# How to change the display of a link source or forward the source of a link

Tags: php, dns

I have a directory on my server that holds lots of images. A plugin I've made pulls these photos from this base directory on our server and displays them on the user's website.

Right now when you view the source of the page, it obviously shows the image source as being on our server. A client has requested that it shows their site as the source instead.

Is there any way to change the source of this image to show as `images.clientsite.com/example.jpg` instead of `images.mysite.com/example.jpg`?

We have access to add any records to the domain along with any programming on their side. If not, what would your recommendation be as a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to actually place all of the images on your client's site.

A work around would be to use an .htaccess rewrite. So in your client's image folder you do:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://images.mysite.com/$1 [L]
```

The links in the HTML will look like the client's site however if the client copies and pastes the image link into the browser it will redirect to your site.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds perfect. I'll be trying it out!